# Haskell function to reverse an IO String

Tags: haskell, monads

How can a function be written in Haskell that takes an IO String and returns the string reversed.

```
rev :: IO String -> IO String
rev s = ...
```

Comment: Do you know how to reverse a `String`?

Comment: @duplode: yes, `reverse s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a short answer:

```
fmap reverse
```